# Apply color ramp to a face?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, node-editor

I am trying to apply a color gradient to single face of a mesh, selected using the edit view. I made a color ramp in the texture view but I can't figure out for the life of me how to paint that onto the mesh. It looks like only material tab changes the render. How can I use the color ramp from the textures tab on the face?

The Material -> gradient only has a black/white gradient, how do I change the color of that?

[image]

Comment: You need to use a "Color Ramp" node in the materials editor. I will post an answer if no one else has when I get back from lunch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using cycles so you'll need a node setup, similar to this

[image]

where you see that there are two materials. The "gradient" one is "assigned" to the single face, while all the rest uses the default grey one.

The material needs a factor that rules the Colorramp transition, provided by a Gradient Texture, which needs the coordinates to be mapped to that face only: for this you need a UVmap: in edit mode select only the face, press <kbd>U</kbd> and select "unwrap". Done.

Answer (score -1):

you have to create a new material for that face then select it in edit mode then use "assign" it to that face 
you should uv unwrapp your model or at least that face since it's going to contain a texture